# Where can I find a function to change things like i'm to I'm?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'm looking for a function that can change things like i'm to I'm, theyre to they're, i to I  ect.

Does anyone know where I can find one?

If not, what would be the best way to approach this? 
The only thing I have in mind is using something like

```
rawMessage = rawMessage.Replace("theyre", "they're");
```

Its for a chat room project, thanks!

Comment: You're not going to find anything builtin that's for sure.

Comment: @Jeff: Yes it is built in to .NET 4 :-)  See my response.

Comment: @EricJ.: Not exactly what I imagined but I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to make an autocorrect feature.  First you need to build a list of corrections

```
Dictionary<String, String> Corrections = new Dictionary<String, String>();
Corrections["i'm"] = "I'm";
Corrections["i"] = "I";
Corrections["theyre"] = "they're";
...
```

Then you need to replace words in your text:

```
String result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b[A-Za-z']*\b", CorrectWord);
```

Then you need to lookup the words:

```
private String CorrectWord(Match match)
{
    String correction;
    if(Corrects.TryGetValue(match.Value, out correction))
        return correction;
    return Match.Value;
}
```

The above code it not tested nor compiled.

Hope that this will help you in your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a spell checking library to correct such typos, e.g.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.aspx

If the built-in WPF spell checker doesn't meet your specific needs, there are many other spell check libraries on the net.

http://www.aspnetspell.com

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/spellcheckdemo.aspx

http://www.markandey.com/2010/03/how-to-write-your-own-spell-checker.html

etc.

Comment: The spell checker would catch "i'm" vs "I'm"?

Comment: I'm looking for something that only changes a list of words. Mainly words like "that's"

Comment: Yes they can... open a MS Word document and type in i'm to see how that particular spell checker corrects casing...

Comment: @EricJ. - MS Word does much more than just spell checking. Are you saying that the `System.Windows.Controls.Spellcheck` class is a full implementation of the language processing available in MS Word?

Answer (score 1):

To use brute-force to change a short, simple list of words, it's trivial to use string.Replace() or Regex. This would work reasonably well for words like "theyre" -> "they're" and "youre" -> "you're".

However, to detect the grammatical structures that require an "it's" or an "its", "your" or "you're", correctly choose between "their", "there" and "they're", or "users" and "user's" and "users'" or detect the difference between "I can't", "The cant of the ship" or "Mr James Cant" in all cases are considerably more complex - even most humans are incapable of getting it right.

For this you'd need a grammar checker. If you've tried commercial ones like the one in MS Word (which is partially responsible for how slow Word is, and then almost always suggests incorrect "corrections" which just make you want to throw your laptop out of the window) you'd realise that you are onto a losing battle.

Be careful of simple replacement schemes. I once posted a message to a chat forum mentioning the town "Scunthorpe" and four letters were changed to asterisks, drawing attention to a rude word nobody would have noticed otherwise. So make sure you apply any processing to *words*, not just sequences of characters (this is where Regex will be much easier than string.Replace).

Ultimately, changing people's chat-room posts will simply alienate them - it's irritating when a correct message is corrupted by a computer that thinks it knows better, and unpleasant to realise the computer is telling you that you're stupid. And if your name is James Cant, you'll have to invent a pseudonym.

This is probably why chat rooms don't usually try to autocorrect users' posts.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll probably just use string.Replace for a few select words